# How to format a partition as JFFS2?

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I tried many applications to format an empty USB drive with a [JFFS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFFS2) filesystem, but I haven't found a tool that would let me do it.

- `gnome-disk-utility` doesn't list it
- `gparted` doesn't list it
- `mkfs.jffs2` build the file system from directory, and *I don't want that*
- `flash_eraseall` fails with the error `can't initialize libmtd`

I'm trying to use it with my router, a [R8000](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/r8000.aspx) running [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFFS2 is not designed for use on regular block devices such as those implemented via USB storage or your hard drive controller - it's designed for embedded devices and when you have direct MTD access to the flash chips.

It isn't possible to use it on a block device except with some fairly advanced hacks, such as [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/how-to-use-jffs2-or-ubifs-to-avoid-data-corruption-and-increase-life-of-the-sd-c) that details using a kernel trick called "block2mtd" to emulate an MTD interface on top of a block device.  This is so impractical as to be an intellectual curiosity only, don't do it in the real world.

JFFS2 is also designed for very small amounts of flash storage on the order of tens of megabytes, and performance may tank for larger volumes.

It's worth noting that modern flash media like USB flash drives and memory cards internally implement a feature called wear-leveling, which addresses one of the main issues that log-structured filesystems like JFFS2 sought to address by reducing erase cycles and spreading writes over the space of the drive.  This will also negate most benefits of such a filesystem.  The wear-leveling on cheaper USB flash drives and memory cards is a low-performance type called dynamic wear-leveling, which moves data around when needed.  Some more premium USB flash drives and memory cards, as well as SSDs, use a higher performance wear-leveling called static wear-leveling, in which data may be moved around while the drive is idle to pre-prepare empty blocks ready for writing, significantly speeding up small write operations.

If you want to experiment, you could try experimenting with a filesystem like [NILFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NILFS).  But, it's much slower than traditional file systems at some tasks.  You may be surprised to find traditional filesystems like ext4 to be faster than you thought.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need to format your USB drive or memory stick to JFFS2. Just use a partition named JFFS and formatted with ext2. Enable USB disk services and it should be automatically mounted by DD-WRT. I use a memory stick on my R7800 running DD-WRT f/w. Check out the settings in GUI tabs USB and NAS. There’s also a jffs setting somewhere in administration.